# NOT an array reference error in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm getting an error in Perl and I can't work out why.

Error: Not an ARRAY reference at Service.pm, line 20

```
my $array = [ { name => 'George', surname => 'Marley' } ];
my $helper = CustMessage->new();
$helper = CustMessage->getMessage($array);
```

then in my utility file I have:

```
sub getMessage {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    my $stringsArray = shift;

    my $strings = Service->new({
        serviceId => $self->_serviceId(),
    });

    return unless $strings;

    $strings->getStrings($stringsArray);
}
```

and then in the Service method is:

```
sub getStrings {
    my ($stringsArray, $self) = shift;
    my @keys = map({ $_->{'name'} } @{$stringsArray});
    my $key = join('', @keys); 
    $key = MIME::Base64::encode($key);

    my %results;
    $results{$key} = $self->_callStrings->($stringsArray);
    $results{$key}->initialize();

    $results{$key} = $self->{serviceCalls}->{getStrings};
    return $self->{serviceCalls}->{getStrings};
}
```

The error is on line 2 of the getStrings method in Service.pm:

```
my @keys = map({ $_->{'name'} } @{$stringsArray});
```

Comment: Missing `,` in `my ($stringsArray $self) = shift;`?

Comment: Nicely spotted but unfortunately that's not the issue. Think I accidentally removed that whilst copying and pasting (there's strange).

Comment: why is `$helper` an object first and then reassigned the value of the output of `getMessage`? I'm more used to seeing things like: `my $helper = CustMessage->new(); my $msg = $helper->getMessage($array);`. I guess if you don't use `$helper` again as an object then the reassignment works? Is this a typical pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RE: I'm getting an error in Perl and I can't work out why. Error: Not an ARRAY reference at Service.pm, line 20

Try

```
my ($self, $stringsArray) = @_;
```

instead of

```
my ($stringsArray, $self) = shift; 
# $self is always undef here due one element list assignment
```

since `getStrings()` is object method and object instance is always first element in `@_` array.

Comment: Please comment on which part is wrong in above answer when down voting.

Answer (score 2):

The lines

```
my $helper = CustMessage->new();
$helper = CustMessage->getMessage($array);
```

are very odd. You are creating a new `CustMessage` object in `$helper` and immediately discarding it and overwriting it with the result of

```
CustMessage->getMessage($array);
```

which, apart from any inheritance that may be going on, is identical to

```
getMessage('CustMessage', $array);
```

and I am suspecting that you don't have a real class defined as you call it your *"utility file"*

Because `getMessage` receives its arguments like this

```
my ($self, $args) = @_;
my $stringsArray = shift;
```

you are left with

```
($self, $args) = ('CustMessage', $array)
$stringsArray  = 'CustMessage'
```

and you never use `$args` again so your array reference is lost.

I cannot be sure what it is you actually want, because, as I said, I suspect that you don't have a proper `CustMessage.pm` file. But you could try

```
my $helper = CustMessage->new;
my $message = $helper->getMessage($array);
```

and then

```
sub getMessage {
    my ($self, $stringsArray) = @_;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Sort of off topic for the OP (whose issue has been resolved I guess) but see my comment above regarding: `my $helper = CustMessage->new(); ...` is it just superfluous code?

Comment: @G.Cito:  I'm not clear that the accepted answer catches all the errors in the question, but the OP seems happy. Take a look at my first paragraph -- you'll see that I agree with you about that line of code, although I'm not at all sure the OP has written a proper `CustMessage.pm` module as he calls it his *“utility file”*